# Reading from two .txt file using fscanf in C, storing in structs and outputitng in .txt file

Tags: c, data-structures

Description: program read data from 2 files, store them in structs,ask user for  (city or place of residence), if city name matches with that stored in file, program displays output(student, national_ID,name) and store  in a file.

My question is that, the above code that i wrote does not work. it gives me a "no information" even when i enter a city which is on the file.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #define MAX_LEN 20
 #define MAX_LINE 7

typedef struct studentdata
 {
char NATIONAL_ID[20];   
char NAME[20];
char STUDENT_CODE[20];
char CITY[20];
}studentdata;

int main(void)
{
 int i;
 char x=0, CITY[MAX_LEN];  
 studentdata y[MAX_LINE];
 char temp[20];
 char temp1[20];
 char count=0;                                        

FILE *fi = fopen("employee1.txt",  "r");

if (fi == NULL)
{
          printf("error data");
            exit(0);
}
FILE *fp = fopen("student1.txt",  "r");

if (fp == NULL)
{
          printf("error data1");
            exit(1);
}

 i = 0;
printf("Enter city\n");
scanf("%s",CITY);


//i = 0;
    FILE *fa = fopen("student2.txt", "w");
     if (fa == NULL)
{
          printf("error data2");
            exit(2);
}

 while(fscanf(fi, "%s %s %s", y[i].NATIONAL_ID, y[i].NAME, y[i].STUDENT_CODE) == 4) 
                i++; 


count=i;
```

I am sure the error is within this loop but can't just find it.

```
  while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s", temp,temp1) == 2)       
   {      

   for(i=0; i< count;i++)
   {

    if (strcmp(y[i].NATIONAL_ID,temp)==0)
     {
       strcpy(y[i].CITY,temp1);        

        if (strcmp(y[i].CITY,CITY)==0)
         {               
            fprintf( "%s\t  %s\t %s\t  %s\t\n",  y[i].NATIONAL_ID, y[i].NAME, y[i].STUDENT_CODE, y[i].CITY);

            x++;    
          }
     }
   }
 }  

 fclose(fa);
if(!x)
{

    printf("no information\n");

}

fclose(fi);
fclose(fp);
 return 0;
```

}

Comment: Have you verified that the strings you think you are reading in are what you are actually reading in?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that nothing is being read from file into the in first while loop -

```
 while(fscanf(fi, "%s %s %s", y[i].NATIONAL_ID, y[i].NAME, y[i].STUDENT_CODE) == 4) 
        i++;
```

As you match for 3 arguments but checks `fscanf`'s return against `4` which will be false and loop will not iterate and `i` remains `0` , so as `count`.

Therefore , your this inner loop won't run-

```
 for(i=0; i< count;i++)           //count=0
```

and thus you don't get your output .

Modify your loop to -

```
while (fscanf(fi, "%s %s %s", y[i].NATIONAL_ID, y[i].NAME, y[i].STUDENT_CODE) ==3) 
/*       see fscanf's return is checked against 3       */
            i++;
```

Note that an easy way to spot this problem would be to print the information as it is read, or print the array after the read is complete.